# Is it possible to include the current script in the current script?

Tags: php, include

Is it allowed for one to do:

`main.php`:

```
//some code....

include "main.php";

//some more code....
```

Wouldn't this cause issues?

Does PHP allow for this to occur? and if it does, what could a reason be for doing this?

Comment: isn't it kinda similar to the idea of recursion?

Comment: @user1301840 I guess so. but this would be a deep file recursion.

Comment: @ComFreek I have. It works if you put **all** the correct safeguards... But once you don't --- ***pfft***

Comment: You can, but you must specify a break-point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not a good idea or good design.

If your include is unconditional (i.e. not guarded by an `if` statement), php will eventually terminate because of memory or CPU time restrictions.

Comment: What does that mean `unqualified`?

Comment: @Neal Probably means if you 'let it run forever'

Comment: so pretty much the same as recursion

Comment: @Neal Sorry, `unconditional` is the better term. It means your include  is in the top level.

Answer (score 2):

If you're declaring any classes or functions, you'll have problems.

As you can't declare them twice. I don't see why you would need to do something like that though. Any particular reason?

Comment: What type of problems? Is there a way to **prevent** the problems from occurring?

Comment: Well I guess for functions (`if ( function_exists() === false) {//declare function}`) and same with classes `class_exists`. but it's still not a very good idea.